# Kernel modules for compiled kernel

Tags: debian, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I cannot find kernel-headers.

For the first time I compiled and installed the latest kernel (4.0.3)
on my Debian Wheezy, and now I am trying to install `ndiswrapper`
using module assistant.

For that, I should specify where the
`linux-headers` is, so I specified the compiled folder but it didn't work.
Then I searched in the directory `/usr/src/` and still I couldn't find it.

Answer (score -1):

You should try:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

if you haven't